# Would Gust of Wind affect a Vampire in Gaseous Form?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, undead

**Scenario**

I had some players fighting off a vampire's attack. The vampire was a sorcerer and rather than dying to the player characters, he casted [Gust of Wind](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gustOfWind.htm) and used his Gaseous Form ability to propel himself pretty far away and in a hurry.

One player started arguing that even in gaseous form he is a still a creature larger than tiny and shouldn't be affected. I told him that it says right there in the description that he assumes gaseous form as the spell, which is affected by wind. Rather than continue to argue with him, I said the vampire casted [Dimension Door](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm) instead and did what he wanted to anyway.

**Party Make-up**

8<sup>th</sup> level Human Paladin of Lawgivers; focusing in smite attacks.
8<sup>th</sup> level Human Swashbuckler of Van Richten Society; focusing in melee and flanking.
8<sup>th</sup> level Human Rogue of Van Richten Society; focusing on skills.
8<sup>th</sup> level Human Rogue of Van Richten Society; focusing on sneak attacks.
8<sup>th</sup> level Human Cleric Lawgivers; focusing on buffs, debuffs, and healing.

**Campaign Details**

Party agreed to Assault Castle Ravenloft. However, I designed the campaign for them to have a protagonist version of Lord Strahd that makes several appearances and harrasses the party throughout the campaign, rather than simply being a monster awaiting in a lair.

Also, beefed up the entire campaign so the characters would finish around level 18, and leveling up Strahd to be a level 20 character. He is going to be two levels higher than the party at all times. Also, I made him a sorcerer rather than a necromancer, simply to reduce MAD.

**Vampire's Tactics**

After trying to Dominate someone, and failing, the party wised up to him. He used a scroll of Haste, as he had won initiative.

Several Sleeps, Charms, and other successful will saves later, the vampire decided that leaving was better than trying to fight it out was.

He assumed gaseous form. He had still spell, silent spell, and eschew materials. He then cast Gust of Wind to propel himself 60 feet away before moving away in gaseous form. He had applied Grease on the ground so the paladin couldn't simply charge attack him after moving away.

Gaseous form was preferrable since the party still had ranged weapons and a severe lack of attacks that could harm his gaseous form. But due to the potential debate (which I hate sometimes) I said, ok, he used Dimension Door and is now 400+ feet away, and instead of using Gaseous Form he turned into a bat and would begin flying away into the air.

Yes the attacks occured at night, not near running water, and not within a building he didn't have permission to be in.

**Question**

Now... dealing with argumentative players aside, am I correct that the vampire should be blown away in Gaseous Form by [Gust of Wind](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gustOfWind.htm), or would be player be correct that he is indeed still a creature of larger size and wouldn't be affected?

**References**

[Gust of Wind](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gustOfWind.htm) states:

> In addition to the effects noted, a gust of wind can do anything that a sudden blast of wind would be expected to do. It can create a stinging spray of sand or dust, fan a large fire, overturn delicate awnings or hangings, heel over a small boat, and blow gases or vapors to the edge of its range.

[Vampire](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/vampire.htm)'s Gaseous Form states:

> As a standard action, a vampire can assume [gaseous form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gaseousForm.htm) at will as the spell (caster level 5th), but it can remain gaseous indefinitely and has a fly speed of 20 feet with perfect maneuverability.

[Gaseous Form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gaseousForm.htm) states:

> The creature is subject to the effects of wind, and it can’t enter water or other liquid.

Comment: What levels and classes are the characters? (It might be irrelevant and challenge the frame, but part of the player's frustration may stem from *either* the PCs being apparently ill-equipped for vampire-slaying therefore thinking the encounter unfair *or* the player picking to play a fighter and expecting to fight dragons and giants yet actually fighting Dracula.)

Comment: **Trivia:** The best—and, perhaps, only—method of dealing with vampires that have assumed gaseous form that *doesn't* also involve DM fiat is the *rod of vapor control* (Far Corners of the World column ["The Hidden Realm Above: Magic Items of the Sky"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fw/20050311a)) (96,000 gp; 5 lbs.); although the effect isn't mind-affecting, it targets a creature's Will save. (If only Ref! Sigh.) The price is high, but maybe the PCs can be lent one.

Comment: Are vampires able to cast spells *after* assuming gaseous form?  I am not familiar enough with this edition to otherwise comment, but the sequence of events got me scratching my head.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast (According to the spell [*gaseous form*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#gaseous-form), the subject "can’t attack or cast spells with verbal, somatic, material, or focus components while in gaseous form. (This does not rule out the use of certain spells that the subject may have prepared using the feats Silent Spell, Still Spell, and Eschew Materials.).")

Comment: @HeyICanChan I understand from that explanation that the Vamp being a sorcerer enables the casting of a spell once in gaseous form plausible.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Plausible but, in the typical campaign, *highly unlikely.* The three feats the vampire must light on fire is a *huge* pile of resources for the vampire to expend on a trick that makes it so it can't use many of its *other* formidable abilities. That is, the typical vampire sorcerer will be 2 levels *lower* with regards to spells than the highest-level PC; for instance, the game thinks a fair encounter is 1 level 12 vampire sorcerer against **4** level 14 PCs!

Comment: @HeyICanChan Based on my search, it may almost be worth making a Q out of my comment, but I don't play 3.5 so I think I'll pass.  Thank You!  once again, High Quality H.I.C.C. productions is in operation! :-)  Someone else may wish to ask that question for a more detailed exploration of the spell casting Vampire in Gaseous Form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

As stated in the spell Gaseous Form:

> **The creature is subject to the effects of wind**, and it can’t enter water or other liquid.

Emphasis Mine, size doesn't matter in a gaseous form, as you will be subject to the effects of wind as any other gas would be

> In addition to the effects noted, a gust of wind can do anything that a sudden blast of wind would be expected to do. It can create a stinging spray of sand or dust, fan a large fire, overturn delicate awnings or hangings, heel over a small boat, and **blow gases or vapors** to the edge of its range.

With Rules as Written, you can definitely cast Gust of Wind as a standard action, then using your move action to move into the gust, to carry you along.

---

If I was GM though, I would rule against this use, as the spell to me seems intended that a single blast of wind comes from the caster, moving away.  The actual ability of the caster to get caught in the gust seems very ambiguous.  It's your game though, and if you feel that the Vampire would be best served as a storyline villain, and not just a once off, that's something to discuss with the table.  Just make sure you don't have anyone ready to snipe him off after the 60 ft. that he moves.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68194/discussion-on-answer-by-nyoze-would-gust-of-wind-affect-a-vampire-in-gaseous-for).

Answer (score 6):

## No...

Even if the vampire somehow has the ability cast *gust of wind* while in *gaseous form*, *gust of wind* 's Effect line (emphasis mine),

> Line-shaped gust of severe wind **emanating out from you** to the extreme of the range [, which is 60']

as well as its description (emphasis mine)

> This spell creates a severe blast of air (approximately 50 mph) that **originates from you**, affecting all creatures **in its path**

show that the caster is the origin of the line-shaped effect.

The wind begins at the caster and emanates outward in a 60' line for 1 round. It affects creatures within the area, but the caster isn't within the area; he's the origin of it.

### But...

Within another caster's *gust of wind* the gaseous vampire should definitely be affected as if it were a gas or fog, and be pushed to the extent of the effect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't whether gust of wind would propel the cloud, it's that per the wording of the spell, the caster (the gassy vamp) is the ***source*** of the wind, but ***not*** in the wind ("severe blast of air (approximately 50 mph) that originates from you"). If he has some Renfield-ish type casting for him when he goes poof, it works quite well since 50 mph is about 73 feet per second and based on how airspeed works that would directly add to his movement rate, making it fairly tough to keep up with him.

Answer (score -1):

It specifically says a creature that is under gaseous form is affected by the gust of wind spell so yes the vampire would be affected.And me personally as a DM if I show you that it is affected by a source and you keep arguing being in a castle you step on trap ceiling falls you got crushed

Comment: You shouldn't try to solve out of game problems with in-game solutions. Killing a PC because a player is annoying you is bad DMing. If a player is annoying you, you should deal with that with an out of character discussion, preferably in private.